# Standardizing at country level using only past data in R

Tags: r, stata

I want to transform the following Stata code to R:

```
forvalues j=1/17 {
    forvalues i=1870(1)2015 {
        qui sum 'var' if country==`j' & year<=`i' 
        scalar mean_x = r(mean)
        scalar std_x = r(sd)
        replace stdup_`var'=(`var'-mean_xt)/std_xt if country==`j' & year==`i'
    }
}
```

My try:

```
for (j in 1:17){
  for (i in 1870:2015){
    mean_var <- colMeans(c1[country==j & year <= i, 'var'], na.rm = TRUE)
    sd_var <- sd(as.numeric(unlist(c1[country==j & year <= i, 'var'])), na.rm = TRUE)
    c1 <- c1 %>%
      mutate(stdup = ifelse(country==j & year == i, (var - mean_var)/sd_var, stdup))
  }
}
```

Is there a nicer and more efficient way to solve it? The code works but the for loop takes approximately 15 seconds, which is not fast enough.

Comment: Could you share your `c1` data, using something like `dput(c1)`?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to ask a question to state what you want to achieve in R.

My understanding is you wanted to generate a `stdup` (z-score) for each `country` and `year`. As mentioned by Nick Cox, there is also a `foreach` loop for `var`. I use `mtcars` data as an example:

```
library(dplyr) 
df <- mtcars
```

If we want to three layers of loops: for each of variables: `mpg, disp, wt, qsec` by each combination of `vs`  and `am`:

```
stdup <- function(x) (x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
new_df <- df %>% group_by(vs, am) %>% 
    mutate(across(c("mpg", "disp", "wt", "qsec"), stdup))
```

Comment: It's tacit also that the OP is looping over some variables.

Comment: Yes, `group_by(country, year)` is for looping over all `country` and `year` values.

Comment: Surely, but in addition the local macro reference `\`var'` indicates a surrounding `foreach` loop.

Comment: True. I have revised my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

As this is flagged Stata too, Stata people might be interested in a way of doing it without loops,  using `rangestat` from SSC. This won't fit easily in a comment.

```
rangestat (mean) mean_`var'=`var' (sd) std_`var'=`var', int(year . 0) by(country) 

gen std_`var' = (`var' - mean_`var') / std_`var'
```

Here the local macro references

```
`var'
```

as in the question indicate that this is the core part of a loop over some variable names. Naturally, you can replace those local macro references by a particular variable name if that is wanted instead.